# what additional details required to login using requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to log into a website. I have taken this code form website

```
<form class="login-form">
   <div class="form-group"><label for="email" class="text-input-label">Email<input id="email" type="email" name="email" required="" value=""></label></div>
   <div class="form-group"><label for="password" class="text-input-label">Password<input id="password" type="password" name="password" required="" value=""></label></div>
   <div class="remember-block">`enter code here`
      <div class="checkbox-group checkbox-group__white"><input type="checkbox" id="rememberMe" name="rememberMe"><label class="checkbox-group__pseudo-checkbox" for="rememberMe"></label><label for="rememberMe" class="remember-label">Remember me</label></div>
      <a class="reset-pass-link" href="/reset-password">Reset password</a>
   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded submit-btn">Login</button>
</form>
```

I have written this to log into that website. But it giving 405 error.

```
import requests

# Fill in your details here to be posted to the login form.
payload = {
    'email': 'xxxx',
    'password': 'js@cen18'
}
login_url = 'https://app.uplead.com/login'
# Use 'with' to ensure the session context is closed after use.
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
    p = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    # print the html returned or something more intelligent to see if it's a successful login page.
    print p.status_code
```

What additional details required to login into the website?
Thanks.

Comment: Indicates wrong http method. Have you tried get instead of post?

Comment: Alternatively, have you used your browser's developer tools to examine the specific http request made when you submit the form in the browser?

Comment: hi @schwobaseggl, I have tried with GET method, it is giving 200 status code. when I print p.text, it is showing some javascript code.

Comment: hi @larsks, I don't have knowledge on those tools, Can you suggest if you have any. thanks.

Comment: why are you using `from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter`?

Comment: The `action` attribute is missing from the `form` tag. The value of the attribute is a function call that performs authentication like: `<form action="login()">`. You must also specify a method attribute `method=POST` in the `form` tag like `<form action="login()"> method=POST`>. Next, you do not need to call the HTTPAdapter class to make a simple POST request. Is there any specific reason to use that?

Comment: Hi @user8212173, I could not find any method = post or <form action="login()">. you can see there is no post method in the code which I posted above. Can you please suggest where I can find that.